# host many domain to the same server

Tags: linux, apache, hosting, virtualhost

i have this domain:

> site 1: /var/www/portail1

with this conf:

> /etc/httpd/conf.d

what i want to do is to add this domain to the same server:

> site 2: /var/www/portail2

But my question here is the site 1 call the conf.d by default, and i need a second conf.d 
for the site 2, so how i can tell site 2 to search his conf from ( for example /etc/httpd/conf2.d)?

Comment: You don't need to create additional conf.d. Just add an additional VirtualHost directive in your apache configuration.

Comment: i know but i have to get two domain totally independent (i am not the manager :p) so i need to create a new /etc/httpd, but i have to add this to the httpd service in /etc/init.d/httpd... i don't know if u get what i say???

Comment: I guess I understand. I wrote an answer.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there should be Include directive in your main apache configuration: either httpd.conf or apache2.conf.

In my ubuntu apache2.conf, it is something like that:

```
# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

So, if you add another conf file inside conf.d/ or sites-enabled/ then it will be automatically included and read by apache during start.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple virtual hosts in single server. Look [Virtual host examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for example.